# How to extract random dates targets/sales data from monthly targets

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have monthly targets defined for the different category of items for the complete year.

Example:

```
January Target for A Category - 15,000
January Target for R Category - 10,000
January Target for O Category - 5,000

Actual Sales for A Category January - 18,400
Actual Sales for R Category January - 8,500
Actual Sales for O Category January - 3,821
```

The SQL query to compare actual sales with target will be simple as follows:

```
  SELECT   TO_CHAR (Sales_Date, 'MM') Sales_Month,
           Sales_Category,
           SUM (Sales_Value) Sales_Val_Monthly,
           Target_Month,
           Target_Category,
           Target_Value
    FROM   Sales_Data, Target_Data
   WHERE   TO_CHAR (Sales_Date, 'MM') = Target_Month
           AND Sales_Category = Target_Category
GROUP BY   TO_CHAR (Sales_Date, 'MM'),
           Target_Month,
           Target_Category,
           Sales_Category,
           Target_Value;
```

Now I have a requirement that user will input `FROM_DATE` and `TILL_DATE` in the report parameter and the starting/ending date can be random, it will not represent a complete month or week, the start date can be `12/01/2018` and end date can be `15/01/2018`, i.e., data for 4 days. The result should calculate the actual data for 4 days, calculate the target for 4 days considering the fact that there will be 6 working days (Sunday is a holiday) and if the date range includes Sunday, it should not be considered.

Also, the number of days in a month should be considered and the date parameters may contain some days from one month and some days from another month or maybe more than one month.

```
Target_Table (Target_Data)          
Target_Year      Target_Month      Target_Category Target_Value
2018            01                 A                15000
2018            02                 A                8500 
2018            03                 A                9500 
2018            01                 R                15000
2018            02                 R                8500 
2018            03                 R                9500 
2018            01                 O                15000
2018            02                 O                8500 
2018            03                 O                9500 


Sales Table (Sales_Data)                                    
Inv_Txn         Inv_No    Sales_Date      Item_Code Sales_Category    Qty  Rate    Sales_Value  Inv_Locn Inv_SM_ID
A21            2018000001 02/01/2018      XXXX         A               2   5.5      11             O001     XXXX
R32            2018000001 27/02/2018      XXXX         R               3   9.5      28.5           O305     XXXX
O98            2018000001 12/03/2018      XXXX         O               12  12.5    150             O901     XXXX
U76            2018000001 18/01/2018      XXXX         A               98  5.5     539             O801     XXXX
B87            2018000001 19/02/2018      XXXX         R               2   9.5      19             O005     XXXX
A21            2018000002 13/03/2018      XXXX         R               45  9.5     427.5           O001     XXXX
B87            2018000002 14/03/2018      XXXX         O               12  12.5    150             O005     XXXX

Desired Output (From Date: 27/02/2018 Till Date: 06/03/2018)        
 Target_Category Target_Value      Sales_Value
    A             87.52            21.88
    A             96.25            24.06
    A             74.25            18.56
    R             100.25           25.06
    R             800.2            200.05
    R             25.1             6.28
    O             75.5             18.88
    O             98.1             24.53
    O             25.5             6.38
```

Comment: When you say that Sundays "should not be considered," what exactly do you mean?

Comment: For example, iff the user enters from date as 26/02/2018 and end date as 12/03/2018, the range contains 15 days including 2 sundays, so the target value will be calculated for 13 days.

Comment: So the month's target value will be pro-rated based on the number of working days in the date range and the number of working days in the month? Are there any holidays apart from Sunday?

Comment: yes, the monthly targets are set according to the number of working days for each month (excluding Sundays and public holidays). I didn't think about the public holidays, yes it should be excluded, that maybe i can put in a table.

Comment: You might consider creating a BUSINESS_CALENDAR table which contains dates which are valid business days.

Comment: So, for Sundays and holidays, there won't be any entries in Sales table. correct?

Comment: yes because no entry will be made for sunday as they will not be working.

Comment: Your expected output should not show the values for  each `Sales_Month` right? Then it would be meaningless. What you would want is a cumulative sum for each `Target_Category/Sales_Category` if I'm not wrong?

Comment: yes, but the sales value and target value should be calculated according to the working days.

Comment: So, why don't you show some sample records and the format of the output correctly for this new expected case?

Comment: Have added some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step might be to see whether we can get the number of Sundays in a given month. As it turns out, we can - and we don't have to use any SQL tricks or PL/SQL:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY FROM LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) ) AS month_day_cnt
     , CEIL( ( LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')) - NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')-1, 'SUN') + 1 ) / 7 ) AS sunday_cnt
  FROM dual;
```

This will give us the number of days in a given month as well as the number of Sundays. All we need to do is subtract the latter number from the former to get the number of working days. We can work that into your initial query (by the way, I suggest using `TRUNC()` instead of `TO_CHAR()` since your users might want a date range that spans more than one calendar year):

```
SELECT TRUNC(s.Sales_Date, 'MONTH') AS Sales_Month
     , EXTRACT( DAY FROM LAST_DAY( TRUNC(s.Sales_Date, 'MONTH') ) ) - CEIL( ( LAST_DAY(TRUNC(s.Sales_Date, 'MONTH')) - NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(s.Sales_Date, 'MONTH')-1, 'SUN') + 1 ) / 7 ) AS working_day_cnt
     , s.Sales_Category, SUM(s.Sales_Value) AS Sales_Val_Monthly
     , t.Target_Value -- Target_Month and Target_Category are superfluous
  FROM Sales_Data s INNER JOIN Target_Data t
    ON TO_CHAR(s.Sales_Date, 'MM') = t.Target_Month
   AND TO_CHAR(s.Sales_Date, 'YYYY') = t.Target_Year
   AND s.Sales_Category = t.Target_Category
 GROUP BY TRUNC(s.Sales_Date, 'MONTH'), Sales_Category, Target_Value;
```

Now given a start date and an end date, we can generate the number of working days for all the months in between those dates as follows:

```
SELECT TRUNC(range_dt, 'MONTH'), COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT start_dt + LEVEL - 1 AS range_dt
      FROM dual
   CONNECT BY start_dt + LEVEL - 1 < end_dt
) WHERE TO_CHAR(range_dt, 'DY') != 'SUN'
 GROUP BY TRUNC(range_dt, 'MONTH');
```

where `start_dt` and `end_dt` are parameters supplied by the user. Putting this all together, we'll have something like the following:

```
WITH rd ( range_month, range_day_cnt ) AS (
    SELECT TRUNC(range_dt, 'MONTH'), COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT start_dt + LEVEL - 1 AS range_dt
          FROM dual
       CONNECT BY start_dt + LEVEL - 1 < end_dt
    ) WHERE TO_CHAR(range_dt, 'DY') != 'SUN'
     GROUP BY TRUNC(range_dt, 'MONTH')
)
SELECT range_month, Sales_Category, Sales_Val_Monthly
     , range_day_cnt, working_day_cnt, Target_Value
     , Target_Value*range_day_cnt/working_day_cnt AS prorated_target_value
  FROM (
    SELECT r.range_month, r.range_day_cnt
         , EXTRACT( DAY FROM LAST_DAY( TRUNC(s.Sales_Date, 'MONTH') ) ) - CEIL( ( LAST_DAY(TRUNC(s.Sales_Date, 'MONTH')) - NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(s.Sales_Date, 'MONTH')-1, 'SUN') + 1 ) / 7 ) AS working_day_cnt
         , s.Sales_Category, SUM(s.Sales_Value) AS Sales_Val_Monthly
         , t.Target_Value -- Target_Month and Target_Category are superfluous
      FROM rd INNER JOIN Sales_Data s
        ON rd.range_month = TRUNC(s.Sales_Date, 'MONTH')
     INNER JOIN Target_Data t
        ON TO_CHAR(s.Sales_Date, 'MM') = t.Target_Month
       AND TO_CHAR(s.Sales_Date, 'YYYY') = t.Target_Year
       AND s.Sales_Category = t.Target_Category
     WHERE s.Sales_Date >= TRUNC(start_dt)
       AND s.Sales_Date < TRUNC(end_dt+1)
     GROUP BY r.range_month, r.range_day_cnt, s.Sales_Category, t.Target_Value
) ORDER BY range_month;
```

If you have a table of public holidays, then those will have to be factored in somewhere as well - both in the `rd` common table expression and from the calculation of working days. If the above doesn't give you a start on that then I can take a look again in a bit and see how the other holidays might be worked in.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of working days between two dates using below query. I added a nonworking date via a table named: holiday_dates and created a series of dates from 12/01/2018 to 15/01. I remove those dates that are either Sunday or holiday. Please let me know if it works for you. Thanks.

```
create table holiday_dates(holiday_dte date, holiday_desc varchar(100));
insert into holiday_dates values(TO_DATE('13/01/2018','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Not a Working Day');

With tmp as (
select count(*) as num_of_working_days 
from ( select rownum  as rn
from all_objects 
where rownum <= to_date('15/01/2018','DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date('12/01/2018','DD-MM-YYYY')+1 ) 
where to_char( to_date('12/01/2018','DD-MM-YYYY')+rn-1, 'DY' ) not in ( 'SUN' ) 
and not exists ( select null from holiday_dates where holiday_dte = trunc(to_date('12/01/2018','DD-MM-YYYY') + rn - 1)))
SELECT   TO_CHAR (Sales_Date, 'MM') Sales_Month,
           Sales_Category,
           SUM (Sales_Value) Sales_Val_Monthly,
           Target_Month,
           Target_Category,
           Target_Value,
           tmp.num_of_working_days 
    FROM   Sales_Data, Target_Data, tmp
   WHERE   Sales_Date between to_date('12/01/2018','DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date('15/01/2018','DD-MM-YYYY')
           AND Sales_Category = Target_Category
GROUP BY   TO_CHAR (Sales_Date, 'MM'),
           Target_Month,
           Target_Category,
           Sales_Category,
           Target_Value;
```